# Python not writing out

Tags: python, linux

I have two questions about my script, how can I get it to output to the file I requested. I ask this because it loops infinitely and when I cancel the script and show the file it is empty. Also, how can I use the variables assigned if I must cancel the script to input anything? Thanks!

```
import subprocess
import datetime
#open results file and assign to results variable, add append rights
results = open("results.txt", "a")
#Run until stopped
while 1:
#split the blah variable by line
#Run tshark command 100 times, then restart script. Assign to blah variable
    blah = subprocess.check_output(["tshark -i mon0 -f \"subtype probe-req\" -T fields -e wlan.sa -e wlan_mgt.ssid -c 20"], shell=True)
splitblah = blah.split("\n")
#repeat  for each line, ignore first line since it contains headers
for value in splitblah[:-1]:
    #split each line by tab delimiter
    splitvalue = value.split("\t")
#Assign variables to split fields
MAC = str(splitvalue[1])
SSID = str(splitvalue[2])
time = str(datetime.datetime.now())
#write and format output to results file
Results.write(MAC+" "+SSID+" "+time+"\r\n")
```

Comment: Oops.... sorry!

Comment: Is the indentation exactly as it appears in your post? If so, the `blah = subprocess.check_output(["tshark -i mon0 -f \"subtype probe-req\" -T fields -e wlan.sa -e wlan_mgt.ssid -c 20"], shell=True)` line will run forever.

Comment: How did you intend to get out of the `while 1:` loop?

Comment: Yep, looks right.

Comment: I would like to kill the loop on a key press, but yes it loops forever as is.

Comment: @axxic3 For future reference, since in Python your code flow is based heavily on your indentation, it is important to maintain that indentation when posting on Stack overflow. There is a {} option in the editor to automatically indent your entire code block as 'code' for the Stack Overflow parser, and I highly recommend making use of the feature in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put a condition in your `while` statement, or the program will (indeed) never stop.

Also, datas are not necessarily written on the disk immediately after `someFileObject.write` function call, you need to call `someFileObject.flush` to insure that.

Comment: Here's what I have so far, sorry I'm pretty new to python. https://pastebin.com/LRrfCkuB

Comment: What can I change about the while loop to have it quit on a keypress like I've tried to do? Thanks!

Comment: what you are doing now should do the work, although that's not the best way I think. What are you trying to do with this script ? Without entering in the detail of the tshark command please, I don't know this tool.
By the way, fileObject.cose() calls fileObject.flush(), no need to call it after.

Comment: I am trying to record the output of that tshark command to separate variables depending on the fields it outputs. Also, when the blah variable is assigned the tshark command would be writing to a file to refer back to if the program is started again. I got it working enough that the variables do in fact work but now I am running across another different issue that I may have to open another thread for.

Comment: I’m not going to troobleshoot your whole script. Look for solutions on the web, read the doc and examples, look for questions here relevant for you, and ask a question if no one ever asked for it (but 95% of the time you don’t have to open a new question).